# GNUCash Auto Account for Taxes

Tags: gnucash

In Canada we have HST (13%) on all business transactions.
When doing book keeping in GNU Cash, is there a way to record the taxes from the transaction automatically on a transaction level?

Example,

$113 total cost
Debit supplies $100, debit HST $13, credit $113 cash.

I have set up the tax table for HST 13%, I feel like I should be able to link that tax rate to each of the expense accounts.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a response from the irc channel:

When using the biz features you can set up a tax table that gets applied to the selected invoice line items.  However for general accounting there is no "automatic" tax split and accounting.

You can use inline math to compute it, tho.  For example, if your amount is 123.45 and you need to split off 4%, you can type, literally, 123.45*.04 and gnucash will compute the result for you.

But you need to split this off manually.

This is a deal breaker for me as a professional accountant.